Route traffic for 10.0.0.0 network to a different router
I added a route for network 10.0.0.0 to use 10.84.202.1. However, a tracert shows it using 192.168.1.1.
The router a hotspot adapter is plugged in. The host still needs to route all 10.* traffic to the corporate router, but it always chooses the hotspot adapter.
> route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.254.0 10.84.202.1 METRIC 1 IF 11
 OK!

> tracert 10.138.33.55

Tracing route to 10.138.33.55 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *

> route PRINT
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...f4 ee 08 53 17 f0 ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2
 18...f4 ee 08 53 17 ef ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
 24...78 8c b5 17 ba 81 ......TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter
 13...f4 ee 08 53 17 ec ......Remote NDIS Compatible Device
 20...00 ff c6 3c e0 60 ......TeamViewer VPN Adapter
 22...7a 8c b5 17 ba 81 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
  3...78 8c b5 17 ba 81 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.84.202.1    10.84.202.202    257
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.99     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.254.0      10.84.202.1    10.84.202.202      2
      10.84.202.0    255.255.254.0         On-link     10.84.202.202    257
    10.84.202.202  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.84.202.202    257
    10.84.203.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.84.202.202    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       169.254.1.2    281
      169.254.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.254.1.2    281
    169.254.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.254.1.2    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.99    261
     192.168.1.99  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.99    261
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.99    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.99    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.84.202.202    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       169.254.1.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.99    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.84.202.202    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       169.254.1.2    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.84.202.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

> route -p ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.254.0 10.84.202.1 METRIC 1
 OK!

> tracert 10.138.33.55

Tracing route to 10.138.33.55 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     2 ms     4 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2




Why are you using a mask of 255.255.254.0 in the route you are adding?
If you are adding this route 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.254.0, that only applies for addresses from 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.1.254. If you really want the entire 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 range, then your mask should be 255.0.0.0.

Thank you! Sometimes I get confused with subnet masks.
